# Conditional Probability: Phil is a compulsive liar who always has a 75% probability of lying.

Tags: probability

Ran into this problem at Brilliant. Their solution seems obviously wrong to me:

Phil is still a compulsive liar who always has a 75% probability of lying. However, we know that he is aware of the winning number in a lottery that consists of choosing a single integer from 1 to a million. He says the winning number is 123. If you were to enter the lottery, which number should you pick to maximize the probability of winning?

Make the assumption that if Phil decides to lie about the winning number, he will pick any incorrect (but possible) number with equal probability.

Answer: 123

Solution: There is a 25% chance that Phil is telling the truth, in which case 123 is the winning number. There is a 75% chance that he is lying, but this leaves the other (10^6)–1 numbers equally likely, and .75*(1/(10^6)–1) is much less than .25.

My Thoughts: I think this is obviously wrong, but I'll explain myself. If you play this game 100 times, Phil will give a wrong number 75 times, and the correct number 25 times. So, he's probably giving the wrong number. Seems simple. To make it more obvious, suppose Phil lies with 99.9999999% probability. (Suppose this means that, of the many many things he says during his long life, only one of them is true.) The number of possible lottery numbers can now be made arbitrarily high, so that whatever number Phil says, we'd have to apply a high probability of it being the correct number (i.e., of Phil telling the truth).

Thoughts?

Comment: If Phil tells you 123, in real life, would you really not pick 123?  If you pick 123 you have a 25% chance of winning the lottery. That is way better odds than you would ever get by random guessing. I would be ecstatic if I had a 25% chance of winning the lottery.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! It's like: He's probably lying, but if he flips two coins and both land heads, he's compelled to tell the truth. So, we should go with 123. ... I see that I was interpreting the question more like, "what's the probability he's telling the truth," than "should you play 123?". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use Bayes' theorem.

P(123 | says '123' ) = $\frac{P(says '123' | 123 )P(123)}{P(says '123')}$ =  $\frac{P(says '123' | 123 )P(123)}{P(says '123'|1)P(1) + P(says '123'|2)P(2)+...P(says'123'|123)P(123)+...P(says'123'|10^6)P(10^6)}$ = $\frac{(0.25)(10^{-6})}{(0.75)(\frac{1}{10^6 -1})(10^{-6})(10^{6}-1)+(0.25)(10^{-6})}$  = 0.25.